# How can I get the Hours from the column created_time of sample dataframe and get count of it as another dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

sample dataframe(df) having following columns:

```
     id     created_time     faid                                            
0    21 2019-06-17 07:06:45  FF1854155    
1    54 2019-04-12 08:06:03  FF30232     
2    88 2019-04-20 05:36:03  FF1855531251     
3   154 2019-04-26 07:09:22  FF8145292   
4   218 2019-07-25 13:20:51  FF0143154   
5   219 2019-04-30 18:50:24  FF04211 
6   235 2019-04-30 20:37:37  FF0671380   
7   266 2019-05-02 08:38:56  FF08070   
8   268 2019-05-02 11:08:21  FF591087
```

May i know how to achieve new dataframe as:

```
hour  count
 07      2
 08      2
  .      .
  .      .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calculating hours from created_time.

groupby hour and count  it

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_time']).dt.hour
res = df.groupby(['hour'],as_index=False)['faid'].count().rename(columns={"faid":"count"})
```

```
hour  count
 07      2
 08      2
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck....any changes?                                                    
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_time']).dt.hour
res = df.groupby(['hour'],as_index=False)['farmer_id'].count()
res.rename(columns={"faid":"count"},inplace=True)

Comment: just remember you need to rename that column you used in count().If you are using farmer_id rename farmer_id ,if faid then rename faid

Comment: `df['count'] = df.groupby(['hour'],as_index=False)['faid'].transform(pd.Series.count)` try this

Comment: @Codenewbie what you add desired output in question you need to save in other dataframe